# Keys in cer and jks file

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have the same key saved in two jks and cer file. Am I right that for this two key files serial number and certuficate value will be the same but SHA-1 will differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SHA-1 of the **file** may be different, but the SHA-1 thumbprint of the certificate itself should be the same.